# Definition of a measurable function?

Tags: measure-theory, definition, measurable-functions

Are these two definitions of a real-valued, measurable function equivalent? ($(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is the measure space.)

> **Definition 1**: $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be measurable if for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{ x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$ (i.e., $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty) \in \Sigma$)
>
> **Definition 2**: $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be measurable if, given the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma'$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $E \in \Sigma ' \implies f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$.

I am under the impression that **Definition 1** is the definition of Lebesgue measurable, that is, $\Sigma '$ must be the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, and $\mu = m$, Lebesgue measure, even though this is probably not true.

The reason I am asking this is that I am having trouble proving the statement that the pointwise limit of a sequence of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable.  I wasn't sure if I could just use the property we derived from **Definition 1** that the pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable, or if **Definition 1** only applies to Lebesgue measurable functions.

Comment: In definition1: $\Bbb R$ with Borel $\sigma$-algeba  .

Comment: Why consider $\Bbb R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra by default? Just to win the measurability of continuous functions.

Comment: @Hamou That makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Hamou ... but this is only true if $X$ is endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma = \mathcal{B}(X)$.

Comment: @zas evidently, we talk about continuous functions, when there is a topology in $X$ and endowed with.... and in the practice $X$ is a topological space that is $X=\Bbb R^n$ or....

Comment: @Hamou The existence of a topology in $X$ doesn't mean that we have to choose the corresponding Borel-$\sigma$-algebra as $\sigma$-algebra. And in practice $X$ is *not* a topological space; there are plenty of counterexamples in probability theory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definition 1 gives measurability of $f$ with respect to the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets. In contrast, Definition 2 defines the measurability of

$$f: (X,\Sigma) \to (\mathbb{R},\Sigma'),$$

i.e. we do not necessarily consider the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, but an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. If $\Sigma' = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, then both definitions are equivalent. This follows from the fact that the family $\{(a,\infty); a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a generator of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Is it normal to learn about Definition 1 long before learning about the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?  We were just taught that a real-valued function is "measurable" (not Borel measurable) if Definition 1 holds.

Comment: @user46944 From my point of view: No, it is not normal. Talking about measurability without defining $\sigma$-algebras doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: So basically, if we say $\{ x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$ is the condition for measurability, then we are saying that the codomain has $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (the Borel $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: @user46944 Yes, exactly. A mapping is Borel-measurable if, and only if, this condition is satisfied.

Comment: And this differs from a function being *Borel measurable* because if a function is *Borel measurable*, it is assumed that the $\sigma$-algebra in the domain is $\mathcal{B}(X)$ (if $X$ is the domain)?

Comment: @user46944 Sorry; seems that my last comment was misleading. If a mapping $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $\{x; f(x)>\alpha\} \in \Sigma$, then $f:(X,\Sigma) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measurable. (That's what I call Borel-measurable.) On the other hand, if $f:(X,\Sigma) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is measurable, then $\{x; f(x)>\alpha\} \in \Sigma$.

Comment: Still a bit confused.  This is what I am understanding: $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is *measurable* with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ if $\{ x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$.  A function is said to be *Borel measurable* if we take $\Sigma = \mathcal{B}(X)$.  Is that right?

Comment: @user46944 A function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is *measurable* if $f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$ for all $E \in \Sigma'$ (see Definition 2). $f$ is *Borel-measurable* if $\Sigma = \mathcal{B}(X)$ and $\Sigma' = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. (And sometimes, at least in probability theory, $f$ is also called Borel-measurable if $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra and $\Sigma' = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.)

Comment: Very clear answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Definition 2 doesn't really make sense. Or, more properly it is not equivalent to def 1 nor useful.

In measurability, you want a sigma algebra (i.e., a measurable space) in your domain, but a topological one in your codomain. Otherwise, if you don't have a notion of convergence in your codomain, you cannot really define a useful integral.

Definition 2, to be equivalent with definition 1, should be that given $E$ **open**, $f^{-1}(E)\in \Sigma$.

Comment: You mean a topological one in the *codomain*, so that all open sets are measurable?  And hence, it makes sense to talk about $f_{n} \to f$?

Comment: Typo corrected. For integration, which is the point of measurability, you need the preimages of open sets to be measurable. You don't need a notion of measurability in the codomain: an integral is a sum of "value of the function times size of the region where you approximate the value".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I will try to internalize it.

Comment: If it helps, think of the "generalized Riemann sums" (or, the same, integrals of simple functions) $$\sum_k\,f(t_k)\,\mu(f^{-1}([t_k,t_{k+1}))).$$

Comment: You're totally right.  Except, I'm not sure where topology comes into play when we have $\int \limits_{X} s \,d\mu = \sum \limits_{ i = 1}^{n} \alpha_{i} \mu(E_{i})$.  $E_{i}$ is not necessarily in the topology, but we do need a topology to talk about convergence almost everywhere, so I think I understand your point. :)

Comment: If you don't have a topology in the codomain, you cannot talk about the limits of the integrals of simple functions.

Comment: You mean such as when applying the Monotone Convergence Theorem to a monotonically increasing sequence of simple functions?

Comment: No, I mean when defining what an integral is. Every definition of integral involves some limit. Limits require a topology to make sense.

Comment: Sure, if we consider taking the supremum of a set as finding a limit point of that set, then I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Definition 1 follows from definition 2 (assuming $\Sigma'$ is the Borel sigma algebra) because of the following lemma.

> Suppose $(X,\Sigma)$ and $(X',\Sigma')$ are two measurable spaces, and suppose that the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma'$ is generated by the family of sets $\Pi$. Then $f : X \rightarrow X'$ is $\Sigma/\Sigma'$ measurable if (and only if, trivially) $f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$ for all $E \in \Pi$.

(Proof hint: $\{ E : f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\Pi$.) Apply the lemma to the family $\{(-\infty,a) : a \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. The Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is slightly larger; it is the [completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure) of the Borel $\sigma$ algebra.

As for your question, here are two hints:

1. $\{\sup_j f_j \leq a\} = \cap_{j=1}^\infty \{f_j \leq x\}$.
2. $\limsup_{j\rightarrow\infty} f_j = \inf_n \sup_{j \geq n} X_j.$

Prove the same relation for $\liminf$ and conclude that both $\limsup f_j$ and $\liminf f_j$ are Borel-measurable. If $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty} f_j$ exists, then ...

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to answer my own question in addition to the other answers given, to make extra clear what is going on here (this will be useful for me as I reference this in the future, and hopefully it will be useful for others, too).

As others have said, our definition of a real-valued function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being measurable is that $\{x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ $((X, \Sigma)$ is a measure space).

But this definition seems so different from the definition that if $(X, \Sigma_{1})$ and $(Y, \Sigma_{2})$ are measure spaces and we have a function $f: X \to Y$, then $f$ is measurable if $E \in \Sigma_{2} \implies f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma_{1}$.

What is going on here is that we automatically assume we are dealing with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in the codomain when we talk about real-valued functions.  Specifically, our function is going from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with measure space $(X, \Sigma)$ as the domain, and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ as the codomain.

But if this is what we are assuming about the codomain, then by the second definition of measurability, shouldn't we be checking that $E \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \implies f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$?  Yes, that is the condition that needs to be satisfied for a real-valued function to be measurable.  So why are we only checking that $\{x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$?

Here is the reason: First, when we assume the codomain has the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, we need to check that the preimage of a Borel measurable set is measurable.  (i.e., if $f: X \to Y$ is a function and $\Sigma$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, we need to check that $E \in \mathcal{B}(Y) \implies f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma$).  But actually, it suffices to show that only the preimage of open sets is measurable, because the set $\{ E \mid E \subseteq Y \, \& \, f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and so if it contains the open sets, then it must contain the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, which is $\mathcal{B}(Y)$.  So that would imply $\mathcal{B}(Y) \subseteq \{ E \mid E \subseteq Y \, \& \, f^{-1}(E) \in \Sigma \}$, and thus the preimage of all Borel measurable sets are measurable (and if the domain is specifically equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then the preimage of all Borel measurable sets are Borel measurable).  So, it suffices to just check that the preimage of an open set is measurable to show that a function is measurable with respect to an arbitrary $\Sigma$ on the domain $X$.

But, we can take it a step further.  We really only need to check that the preimages of the intervals $(\alpha, \infty)$ are measurable for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  This is because we have the following equivalence:

> $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open and $f^{-1}(O) \in \Sigma$ $\iff$ $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) \in \Sigma$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

To prove this equivalence is easy.  For the $\implies$ direction, suppose every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a measurable preimage.  Then since for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $(\alpha, \infty)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$, by assumption $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) \in \Sigma$, as desired.

For the $\impliedby$ direction, suppose for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $\{ x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} = f^{-1}( (\alpha, \infty) ) \in \Sigma$.  This directly implies that for any interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(I) \in \Sigma$.  But every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a countable, disjoint union of open intervals.  So we have if $O \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is open, then since we can write $O = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_{n}$, and $f^{-1}(O) = f^{-1}(\bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_{n}) = \bigcup \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} f^{-1}(I_{n})$, and because $f^{-1}(I_{n}) \in \Sigma$ (since $I_{n}$ is an interval), then $f^{-1}(O) \in \Sigma$, as desired.

> **So at the end of the day, to check that a real-valued function is measurable, by definition we must check that the preimage of a Borel measurable set is measurable.  But this boils down, as shown above, to proving that $\{x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} = f^{-1}( (\alpha, \infty)) \in \Sigma$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, since this implies that the preimage of Borel measurable sets are measurable.**

Note that to check if a real-valued function is *Borel measurable*, it also suffices to check that $f^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, since this implies that the preimage of an open set is Borel measurable, which implies that the preimage of a Borel measurable set is Borel measurable.

Comment: Why the definition use $\{x|f(x)>\alpha\}$? Can I use $\{x|f(x)<\alpha\}$? I guess both serve same thing @layman