# Measurable functions into the unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a very basic question about measure theory (I have just started learning it). Consider the unit interval, with the usual Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}.$ In other words, $\mathcal{B}$ is the sigma algebra generated by $\tau,$ where $\tau$ is the subspace topology on $[0,1],$ which is induced by the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}.$

I am hoping that somebody can help me characterize the measurable functions from some measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma _\Omega)$ to $[0,1]$ (with the aforementioned Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$). I saw a somewhat similar problem posed in a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905415/definition-of-a-measurable-function), but in that case they were interested in measurable functions to the reals. Anyway, that answer caused me to conjecture as follows:

A function $f$ from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$ is a measurable function from $(\Omega, \Sigma _\Omega)$ to $([0,1], \mathcal{B})$ if and only if for each $x \in [0,1]$ we have that $f^{-1} \left( [0,x] \right) \in \Sigma _\Omega .$

I was hoping somebody could tell me if this conjecture is correct, or else how to characterize when a function from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$ is measurable.

Comment: It is correct. Did you try to prove it?

Comment: You should use, that those $[0,x]$-intervals are generators of the Borel-$\sigma$ algebra.